# Append string after each line except header and footer line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to append some string after each line of the file except the header and footer of the files .
So I have used below command to change the range of the lines except header and footer but its deleting header and footer and I do not want to delete the header and footer lines .

```
sed -n '2,5p; '"$str_var"'' abc.dat > abc.dat.temp
```

even I have tried to skip the header and modified other lines by using below command but no options for footer/ trailer line to keep it as unchange .

```
sed '1! s/$/'"$str_var"'/g' abc.dat > abc.dat.temp
```

any suggestions how to change all the lines of the file except the header and footer line and the command should not be deleting the header/footer line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`, for a file of any number of lines:

```
$ awk -v last=$(wc -l < input) 'NR!=1 && NR!=last { print $0 " and more stuff" } NR==1||NR==last { print }' input
header
foo and more stuff
bar and more stuff
baz and more stuff
quux and more stuff
freeble and more stuff
bletch and more stuff
footer
```

Get the number of lines in the input file with `wc`, stash that in an `awk` variable.  Then print the header and footer by themselves, and all other lines with the suffix:

```
NR!=1 && NR!=last {
   print $0 " and more stuff"
} 
NR==1 || NR==last {
    print
}
```

Comment: If you redirect the file, you don't need to filter: `-v last="$(wc -l < input)"`

Comment: A cat with many skins, POSIX be.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the header and footer are one line each: for the first line and the last line, skip further processing. Each line is printed by default.

```
$ seq 10 | sed '1n; $n; s/$/ hello/'
1
2 hello
3 hello
4 hello
5 hello
6 hello
7 hello
8 hello
9 hello
10
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` and in different way append to all lines `s/$/.../` except `!` the first `1` and will `q`uit if it was the last line `$` in advance.

```
sed '$q ;1 !s/$/ append/' <(seq 10)
1
2 append
3 append
4 append
5 append
6 append
7 append
8 append
9 append
10
```

**Or using `awk`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{ getline line} {print line; line=$0 " append";} END{print $0}' <(seq 10)
1
2 append
3 append
4 append
5 append
6 append
7 append
8 append
9 append
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions . It was really useful .
I have written below command to do the same .

str_var=$(awk -F'\|\^' '{print $3}' abc.dat | head -1)

awk -v last=$(wc -l < inputFile) -v l="$str_var"  '{if(NR==1){print $0} else if(NR==last){print $0} else{print $0 l}}' inputFile > outputFile

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

inputfile

```
10
20
30
40
```

command

```
 for i in `awk '{print NR}' inputfile| wc -l| awk '{print $1-1}'`; do sed '2,'$i's/$/praveen/g' inputfile;done
```

output

```
10
20praveen
30praveen
40
```